# How to generate a sequence that show value that is TRUE only in a list using R?

Tags: r

```
a <- c(1:101)
b <- c(rep(c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE),20), "LABEL")
```

I want to generate a sequence that shows only the TRUE value, such as

```
3, 8, 13, 18, 23 ...., 98
```

I try seq()[b] or seq(b) but I failed. What did I missed?

If I want to removed the corresponding item in list a, such that list a become

```
1,2,4,5,6,7,9,10......
```

What should I do?

Comment: the `c(..., "LABEL")` converts the logical vector to `character`..  I think the `b <- rep(c(FALSE, FALSE, ...), 20)` was only needed, then using `which(b)` you get the expected

Comment: `b <- rep(c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE),20)` Then `which(b)[1:5]` returns `[1]  3  8 13 18 23`, for example.

Comment: if you want to keep the "LABEL" argument: `which(b %in% "TRUE")`.

Comment: You should probably stick to asking a single question at a time, but any tutorial on R would answer your second question. Use a negative index like `x[-w]` where `w` are the positions.

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, I modified my question, because I thought that if I used c <- which(b %in% "TRUE"), and a[,!c], everything will be removed.

Comment: Thank you very much, since it is a character, ! will not work, but - will.